# Erro na leitura de strings - está pegando \n do buffer

Tags: java

Estou usando uma variável do tipo `String` para pegar a resposta se quer ou não inserir uma nova conta.

Quando inicio o programa, no `do while` peço o nome do titular. O programa não exibe a pergunta após ler o nome do titular, ou seja, informei o titular, teclei enter, não aparece nada no console. Tenho que teclar enter novamente para exibir a pergunta.

Então, pergunto se quer inserir outra conta e após ler **s** ou **S**, tenho que teclar um segundo enter para pedir o nome do titular. Estou limpando o buffer após inserir o nome e após responder a pergunta. Seguem os fontes:

```
public class ContaCorrente {    

    private int numero;
    private double saldo;
    private String titular;

    private static int numeroReferencia = 0;

    public ContaCorrente(String titular){  
        this.atribuirNumero();  
        this.titular = titular;  
        this.saldo = 0;  
    }  

    public void depositar (double valor) {  
        this.saldo += valor;  
    }  

    public void sacar (double valor) {  
        this.saldo = this.saldo - valor;  
    }  

    public double consultarSaldo () {  
        return this.saldo;  
    }  

    public void atribuirNumero () {  
        numeroReferencia ++ ;  
        this.numero = numeroReferencia;  
    }  

    public void detalharConta () {  
        System.out.println("Conta " + numero);  
        System.out.println("Titular :" + titular);  
    }  

}
```

**outra classe**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;    
public class ContaCorrentePrincipal {

    private static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);    
    private static final int QUANTIDADE_CONTAS = 3;

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        ContaCorrente[] contas = new ContaCorrente[QUANTIDADE_CONTAS];

        String resposta;

        do {  
            int i = 0;  
            contas[i] = criarConta();     
            System.out.println("Quer continuar inserindo contas?");  
            resposta = entrada.nextLine();      
            // limpar buffer  
            entrada.nextLine(); 
            i ++ ;  
        }while ((resposta.equals("s")) || (resposta.equals("S")));  
    }  

    private static ContaCorrente criarConta () {  
        String titular;      
        System.out.println("Informe o nome do titular");  
        titular = entrada.nextLine();      
        // limpar buffer  
        entrada.nextLine();      
        ContaCorrente conta = new ContaCorrente(titular);  

        return conta;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   `    do {  
            int i = 0;  
            contas[i] = criarConta();     
            System.out.println("Quer continuar inserindo contas?");  
            resposta = entrada.nextLine();      
            // limpar buffer  
            entrada.nextLine(); 
            i ++ ;  
        } while ((resposta.equals("s")) || (resposta.equals("S")));  
    }  

    private static ContaCorrente criarConta () {  
        String titular;      
        System.out.println("Informe o nome do titular");  
        titular = entrada.nextLine();      
        // limpar buffer  
        entrada.nextLine();      
        ContaCorrente conta = new ContaCorrente(titular);  
        return conta;  
    }
}`
```

em todos os casos em que vc coloca `entrada.nextLine()` coloque apenas `entrada.next()`

Comment: Sua resposta ficaria melhor se você explicasse por que `next()` e não `nextLine()`